# Python - access module from package that is not imported through __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, name-collision

I'm using one package that with `__init__.py` import only one variable from module, but whole module itself is not exposed. Is there a way to access that module?

Lets look in this case:

Whole package:

```
test_package/
├── __init__.py
└── test_me.py
```

Now contents:

**__init__.py**:

```
from .test_me import test_me
```

**test_me.py**:

```
STATIC = 'static'


class Test:
    pass


test_me = Test()
```

Now if I import package `test_package`. I can only access variable `test_me`, which is an instance of `Test` class. Though I can't access `STATIC` variable, because module itself was not exposed.

Is there a way to access `test_me` module in this case and not only one of its variables?

P.S. If I use `sys` to append path directly to that package's module, it throws error that such module does not exist when I try to import it.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to access the `test_package.STATIC` after you `import test_package`?

Comment: @feliks yes, in my real case I need to use function that lives inside that module. In example case I want STATIC variable. Idea is su access other attributes than were exposed. As in an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the package directory to your path, Python can import any file in that directory as if it were a module by itself.

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(test_package.__path__)
import test_me
print(test_me.STATIC)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (or am I missing something?). If I do exactly as you described, then I get `NameError: name 'test_package' is not defined`. If I first import `test_package` normally and then try to do your way, then when I try to do `import test_me`, I get `ImportError: No module named 'test_me'`

Comment: @Andrius I tested it and it worked for me. Is your test setup *exactly* as you show in the question? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Well i copy pasted the content, so it should be the same. Python 3

Comment: @Andrius I apologize, when I tested I used a hard-coded path. I didn't realize that `test_package.__path__` is a list and not a string. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import them through `__init__.py`, so change its contents to:

```
from .test_me import test_me, STATIC
```

Now the following will work:

```
import test_package
print(test_package.STATIC)
```

Comment: Well of course it will work. I know that. The question was how to access it if it was not imported. If its even possible? The package is not mine, so I cant just modify it. Or I would need to fork that project and customize it. Which I dont want to do it.